# Java out of Memory heap error when calculating shortest paths to all nodes through Dijkstra's algorithm from every node as source

Tags: java, algorithm, out-of-memory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have a network of 7 nodes and 8 links. I have taken the following classes from examples on the internet. I want to calculate the shortest paths from every node to all other nodes. For that, I have written the required **for** loop in Solve (main). But, I am getting the shown output. Shortest paths are fine from the first node, Harrisburg. From the second node, the java out of memory occurs. What do I have to do? Thanks for any help.

Vertex.java

```
    public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {

    public final String name;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Vertex previous;
    public double population, employment;
    public double targetPopulation, targetEmployment;

    public Vertex (String argName, double population, double employment, double targetPopulation, double targetEmployment) {
        this.name = argName;
        this.population = population;
        this.employment = employment;
        this.targetPopulation = targetPopulation;
        this.targetEmployment = targetEmployment;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    //Vertex comparator
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vertex other) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
    }

    }
```

Edge.java

```
public class Edge {

public final Vertex target;
public final double weight;

public Edge(Vertex argTarget, double argWeight) {
    this.target = argTarget;
    this.weight = argWeight;
}

}
```

Dijkstra.java

```
public class Dijkstra {

//simple compute paths function
public void computePaths(Vertex source) {
    source.minDistance = 0.;

    //Visit each vertex u, always visiting vertex with smallest minDistance first
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
    vertexQueue.add(source);

    while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
        Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

        //Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies) {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            double weight = e.weight;

            //relax the edge (u,v)
            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
            if(distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
                //remove v from queue
                vertexQueue.remove(v);

                v.minDistance = distanceThroughU;
                v.previous = u;

                //re-add v to queue
                vertexQueue.add(v);
            }
        }
    }


}

//get shortest path function
public List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target) {
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous) {
        path.add(vertex);
    }

    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

}
```

Solve.java

```
Vertex v0 = new Vertex("Harrisburg", 5, 0.5, 9, 5);
Vertex v1 = new Vertex("Baltimore", 61, 21, 91, 32);
Vertex v2 = new Vertex("Washington", 99, 10, 10, 10);
Vertex v3 = new Vertex("Philadelphia", 159, 30, 100, 45);
Vertex v4 = new Vertex("Binghamton", 10, 10, 10, 10);
Vertex v5 = new Vertex("Allentown", 10, 10, 10, 10);
Vertex v6 = new Vertex("New York", 891, 200, 400, 220);

v0.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(v1, distances[0]),
                                new Edge(v5, distances[1]) };

    v1.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(v0, distances[0]),
                                new Edge(v2, distances[2]),
                                new Edge(v3, distances[3])};

    v2.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(v1, distances[2])};

    v3.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(v1, distances[3]),
                                new Edge(v5, distances[4]),
                                new Edge(v6, distances[5])};

    v4.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(v5, distances[6])};

    v5.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(v0, distances[1]),
                                new Edge(v3, distances[4]),
                                new Edge(v4, distances[6]),
                                new Edge(v6, distances[7]) };

    v6.adjacencies = new Edge[] { new Edge(v3, distances[5]),
                                new Edge(v5, distances[7]) };

Vertex[] vertices = {v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6};

Dijkstra dijkstra = new Dijkstra();

........

for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {

                    for(Vertex v : vertices) {
            v.setMinDistance(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        }
        dijkstra.computePaths(vertices[i]);
        //print out shortest paths and distance

        System.out.println("Shortest paths from "+ vertices[i].name);
        for (Vertex v: vertices) {
            System.out.println("Distance to " + v + ": " + v.minDistance);
            List<Vertex> shortestPath = dijkstra.getShortestPathTo(v);
            System.out.println("Path: " + shortestPath);

            currentAccE[i] = currentAccE[i] + (v.employment)*impedance(v.minDistance);
            currentAccP[i] = currentAccP[i] + (v.population)*impedance(v.minDistance);

        }
    }

........
```

Output:

```
Solve started..........
Shortest paths from Harrisburg
Distance to Harrisburg: 0.0
Path: [Harrisburg]
Distance to Baltimore: 79.0
Path: [Harrisburg, Baltimore]
Distance to Washington: 118.0
Path: [Harrisburg, Baltimore, Washington]
Distance to Philadelphia: 142.0
Path: [Harrisburg, Allentown, Philadelphia]
Distance to Binghamton: 214.0
Path: [Harrisburg, Allentown, Binghamton]
Distance to Allentown: 81.0
Path: [Harrisburg, Allentown]
Distance to New York: 172.0
Path: [Harrisburg, Allentown, New York]
Shortest paths from Baltimore
Distance to Harrisburg: 79.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
at umd.sapeksha.shortestpath.Dijkstra.getShortestPathTo(Dijkstra.java:48)
at umd.sapeksha.shortestpath.Solve.main(Solve.java:109)
```

Comment: What is the problem in the code ?

Comment: As you can see in the output, after the first set of shortest path values from Harrisburg, for the second set from Baltimore, shortest paths are wrong. Baltimore to Harrisburg is not 0 and the paths are being printed wrong too. I suppose the shortest paths are not getting computed again. I want to know why?

Comment: I know you want to use Dijkstra algorithm, but as a suggestion, the [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm would be more efficient, if you could use it.

Comment: I have initialized these variables in the main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the `minDistance` of your vertices to `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` every time you change the source, otherwise the algorithm will use the previously calculated min distances which will obviously be different depending on where you start from.

Comment: Thank you. Where in the loop shall I re-initialize the values of minDistance? I am doing at the start of the loop with v.minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; it still does not give correct shortest paths.

Comment: Try right after `for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++)` in Solve.java

Comment: It works now I guess. But when I set it to POSITIVE_INFINITY again, java out of memory error occurs like this. 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

It would be great if you could provide links to pages that talk about dealing with this. Thank you.

Comment: Probably your `while` loop is not terminating (stack overflow error).  Can you reach every location from every other one? Try to debug where it is occurring.

Comment: I have now modified the question and the output. I don't know if I'm allowed to do that or wait for the forum moderator to do something. The error occurs at path.add(vertex) line of the getShortestPathTo function of the Dijkstra class.

Comment: During your loop when you reset the `minDistance` you should also set `previous` to `null`.  The for loop is not terminating because there is a cycle in the `previous` vertex graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now! I didn't know the exact way the algorithm was working, so couldn't figure these things out.